# To count the unique number of values based on criteria

Tags: excel-formula

Column A is the list of projects and column B is the markets. Both the columns have duplicate values.

In the below example I want to count the number of unique projects in the Hong Kong market. The answer should be 8. I need the formula to calculate the same

I don't have Office 365 so the unique function will not work and I cannot use pivot. Have to use a formula.

This is the sample data the actual list consists of multiple markets and projects of sample size 200. Excel version 2016.

[image]

Comment: Place this in a random unused cell: `=COUNTIF(B2:B13,"*")-COUNTIF(B2:B13,"*;*")` counts all text cells in column and substracts from cells with multi markets

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hong Kong",B2:B13)),MATCH(A2:A13,A2:A13,0)),ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))`

`IF` checks wether `Hong Kong` is part of the market in the `ISNUMBER`, `SEARCH` section. And returns TRUE (1) or FALSE (0).
The `MATCH` part returns the row numbers of the first match of each value it searches in column A. If a value is used more than once the match will return the row number of the first match for each value.
The `ROW(range)-ROW(first_value_in_range)+1` returns a sequence of the count of rows in your range.
`FREQUENCY` checks the occurance of the row numbers from the match-function versus the sequence created from the rows-part. If it occurs more than once FREQUENCY returns the total count of occurrences for the first and returns 0 for any next occurrence.
Finally it's summer by each frequency `>0`.

As this is an array formula you need to confirm the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: Thanks for this formula it works for my one of the sheet but it does not work for the other sheet where some of the cells are blank in the column A i.e. List of projects. Could you suggest how to modify the formula to work for the column even with blank cells and not to count those blank cells?

Comment: It works fine with me, even with blanks: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toLRH.jpg)

Comment: The blanks in the original file are only in column A i.e. list of projects. Project B does not have Blank. So, some of the data are like:

A -  Hong Kong
B -  Hong Kong, Singapore
C  - Hong Kong
Blank -   Hong Kong, Singapore
B  -  Hong Kong, Singapore, China

In this case, the unique number of Hong Kong projects should be 3

Comment: `=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hong Kong",B2:B6))*(A2:A6<>""),MATCH(A2:A6,A2:A6,0)),ROW(A2:A6)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))` Simply added an extra condition: `(A2:A6<>"")', where `*` is to be read as `AND` [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VztJA.jpg)